# Python & Pandas: reading variable.content in pd.read_excel throws error "File is not a zipfile"

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I've this Python script which worked fine but it seems Pandas or Openpyxl or requests has a different version which makes the code not work anymore. The Excel file I pull seems to be the same like before, I've verified that I get a valid file using the browser.
What I am doing is I get a cookie and use requests lib with the cookie to open link_a (which is a URL to an Excel file), then I create a dataframe for this by passing the content of the file fetched.
There's probably a much better way to do this.

```
requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings()
excel_a = requests.get(link_a, verify=False, cookies=a)

# Read the Excel files into one merged dataframe
df = pd.read_excel(excel_a.content, engine="openpyxl")
```

Using Pandas 1.3.1, requests 2.26.0, urllib3 1.26.6, openpyxl 3.0.7

Comment: Please add `print(excel_a.headers["Content-Type"])` immediately after `excel_a = requests.get(link_a, verify=False, cookies=a)` and check what it does output

Comment: Getting a text/html so i think the requests part is the culprit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Getting a text/html so i think the requests part is the culprit.*

Yes. Now you might try adding `print(r.text)` which should output source of page (beware - it might be long). If it does imply your auth data is not correct, either by stating this directly or prompting you to login, then most probably cookies you use expired and you need to get new.

Comment: Thank you, I know where to go with this now :) Definitely a cookie issue